# org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean cast erro

Tags: java, axis2

Estou tentando fazer uma conversão de um sistema que está em java 6 que está funcionando perfeitamente, mas depois de mudar para maven3 e java7 deu erro em uma parte do sistema que não estou percebendo o problema.

```
MinhaCLass_type1 ee = método.get()
```

Tanto a "MinhaClass_type1" como o métodp.get() está sendo implementado por
org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean estou usando axis2 1.5.1, fiz umas buscas nas mudanças do java6 para o 7, mas não encontrei nada.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Qual é o erro? Da forma como a sua pergunta está é difícil alguém conseguir ajudar. Faça a [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como funciona o site e veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável.

Comment: Error:(350, 71) java: incompatible types: xxx_type0 cannot be converted to xxx_type1, como eu disse antes, ambos estão sendo imprementados por org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean

Comment: Leia os links que lhe mandei, edite a sua pergunta com a informação do erro, possivelmente adicione a parte do código que está a dar problemas.

Comment: Obrigado no próximo post irei fazer isso, o problema que coloquei acabei descobrindo o que era. Me passaram o código desatualizado.

Comment: @Michel, como descobriu o problema, seria interessante você mesmo adicionar uma resposta a sua própria pergunta, explicando o motivo do problema e como resolveu.